# How to get first day and last day for every week in a month?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can i get the first day(Monday) and last day(Sunday) for **EVERY** week in a month?

**Example: July 2015**

*Week 1*
First: 29-Jun
Last: 5-Jul

*Week 2*
First: 6-Jul
Last: 12-Jul

*Week 3*
First: 13-Jul
Last: 19-Jul

*Week 4*
First: 20-Jul
Last: 26-Jul

*Week 5*
First: 27-Jul
Last: 2-Aug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
GO

declare @Month date = '150701';
declare @Index int = 1;
declare @StartWeek date;
declare @MonthWeek table ([Week] char(6), StartDate date, EndDate date)

set @StartWeek = DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Month)-1), @Month)

insert into @MonthWeek([Week], StartDate, EndDate)
select 'Week ' + cast(@Index as char), @StartWeek, DATEADD(D, 6, @StartWeek);

select @StartWeek = DATEADD(D, 7, @StartWeek), @Index = @Index + 1;

while DATEPART(M,@StartWeek) = DATEPART(M,@Month) 
begin
   insert into @MonthWeek([Week],StartDate,EndDate)
   select 'Week ' + cast(@Index as char), @StartWeek, DATEADD(D, 6, @StartWeek);

   select @StartWeek = DATEADD(D, 7, @StartWeek), @Index = @Index + 1
end;

select * from @MonthWeek;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 2-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); -- first day of week

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 2-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); -- last day of week
```

[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1648)

Answer (score 0):

i think it Will Help You

```
declare @sdate date='20150601'
declare @edate date=dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(month,1,@sdate))


; with cte as
 (
 select @sdate  as startdate 
 union all
 select dateadd(dd,1,startdate) from cte where startdate < @edate
 )
  select convert(varchar(20),startdate,106)as Date,datename(WEEKDAY,startdate),day(startdate)/7+1 as WEEKNO from cte
  where datename(WEEKDAY,startdate) in ('Monday','Sunday')
     option (MaxRecursion 32665)
```

here is [Demo SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e27b/4)